# Cannot run triggers Oracle forms 12c

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, oracleforms

After installing Oracle 12c database, Weblogic and forms.
I added button on blank form to show message or execute query.
In the runtime the when_button_pressed not work but if I press Ctrl+F11 it executes well.
Not that I move fmx file from Windows machine to Linux machine where weblogic and database are installed.

Comment: When-button-pressed: message (‘hello’);message(‘hello’);

Answer (score 1):

If you really named the trigger `when_button_pressed`, then this is the reason. Triggers - which are built-in into Forms - have a hyphen, not an underline, i.e. `when-button-pressed` is its correct name.

If this is not the case (but a matter of a typo), posting trigger code might help. What does it contain?